# Help! How do I replace a dryer vent hose that runs inside the wall. Should I just hire a professional instead of replacing it myself?

Tags: dryer

[A video link is provided. I’m no expert so I don’t know if I should hire a professional instead](https://imgur.com/a/fKHyxbg)

Comment: Why does it need replacing?  It seems an extension is all that is needed, maybe ten bucks.  A professional charges 50$ plus just to say hello, before work.  If more work is required, that is a good place to practice.  Behind a dryer you will only see, so drywall work does not need to be done perfectly the first time.

Comment: @crip659 looks to me like the duct has started to come unwound.  Gonna be hard to install an extension, because the unraveled part will need to be cut off through the hole.  Unfortunately, the OP doesn't show us the other end, or tell us how long this duct is.  (It also looks kinda like the duct is crushed where it crosses the framing.)  I'm suspecting some drywall repair is gonna be needed for this project.